# Eclipse RCP - Add submenu to existing file menu

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to add submenu to existing file menu.
I tried below:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
       <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.file?after=additions ">
         <command
               commandId="com.my.home.handler.MyHandler"
               id="myTrams"
               label="TRAMS"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Can someone help to add submenu to existing file menu using plugin.xml?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct you locationURI as locationURI="menu:file?after=additions".

Answer (score 3):

The menu id for the File menu is just `file` not 'org.eclipse.ui.file'

For example this is the menu contribution for 'File > Restart':

```xml
<menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:file?after=open.ext">
     <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.restartWorkbench"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.file.restartWorkbench"
           style="push">
     </command>
</menuContribution>
```